# Como acrescentar uma coluna

Tags: r

```
train <- read.csv("train.csv")
train$color <- as.numeric(as.factor(train$color))
train.scale <- scale(train[,2:5])
train.scale$color <- train$color
```

**ERRO:**

> In train.scale$color <- train$color : Coercing LHS to a list

```
structure(list(id = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 4L), bone_length = c(0.354512184582154, 
0.575559905025466, 0.467875498742323, 0.776652460655474), rotting_flesh = 
c(0.35083902671065, 
0.425868432210585, 0.354330420391775, 0.508722549943229), hair_length = 
c(0.465760891829121, 
0.531401378709141, 0.811616089668924, 0.636765579959788), has_soul = 
c(0.78114166586219, 
0.439898877037289, 0.791224973337769, 0.884463692097697), color = c(4, 
5, 1, 1), type = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Ghost", 
"Ghoul", "Goblin"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "bone_length", 
"rotting_flesh", "hair_length", "has_soul", "color", "type"), row.names = 
 c(NA, 
 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obrigado pelos dados em formato de `dput`.
Depois de ver os dados, a resposta é muito simples. A forma correta de calcular os z-scores com `scale` é a seguinte.

```
train.scale <- as.data.frame(sapply(train[, 2:5], scale))
train.scale$color <- train$color
```

**Nota:**
A forma proposta pelo Willian Vieira também daria certo, mas se não usarmos `as.data.frame`, o resultado é de classe `matrix`. Seja como for, mantém-se o `sapply`.

```
train.scale2 <- sapply(train[, 2:5], scale)
train.scale2 <- cbind(train.scale2, color = train$color)
```

Comment: Agora deu certo, obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente, sua pergunta não é reprodutível. Na próxima tente colocar parte dos dados para que possamos reproduzir o erro.

**Resposta**

Você não pode usar `$` em uma matrix, pois uma matrix é apenas um vetor com dimensões. No seu caso tem que usar a função `cbind`:

`train.scale <- cbind(train.scale, newColumn = train$color)`

Comment: Warning message:
In cbind(train.scale, newColumn = train$color) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

Comment: Na amostra que fiz, não obtive esse erro. Se quiser que eu reproduza seus erros terá que postar parte dos seus dados na sua pergunta.

Comment: Como eu faço pra colocar o summary() dos dados na pergunta?

Comment: ou posso colocar um head(). Como voce achar melhor

Comment: utilize `head(train)` e então cole o resultado na questão.

Comment: Não posso utilizar como você colocou, olhe essa explicação: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6532002

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65906/discussion-between-willian-vieira-and-pedro-teixeira).

Comment: A melhor maneira para postar dados é `dput(head(train, 20))`. Poste o output disto na *pergunta*, não num comentário.